# Android Device not detected with USB debugging

Tags: android, debugging, usb, adb

When I plug my phone into my computer with USB Debugging enabled, literally nothing happens. The computer does not even detect a device has been plugged in and the phone does not show the charging LED.

When USB Debugging is turned off, without disconnecting my phone my computer detects it.

I think there's an issue with ADB on the phone as the error occurred after trying to patch ADBD using Chainfire's ADBD insecure.

Comment: Sometimes my computer will stop recognizing devices for debugging, and I have to run `adb kill-server` to reset the adb server process that manages android devices for debugging.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

So long without a reasonable answer?

Vivo Y55A, but your solution is probably similar, because this is a pretty generic issue. With platform-tools installed, using "adb devices" I saw nothing attached. Developer Options was of course activated (via tapping Build Number 8 times), and USB Debugging was set to "on." Below those options are "USB Debugging Mode" which I had forgotten to set to MTP (it was on Picture Mode or something). Still no device.

I changed the USB cable and that solved the problem. Aside from being faulty, some cables may have only the power connectors wired, and the serial lines may not have any connection. Do try at least a couple of other cables, as well as a couple of other USB ports (sometimes the driver pointing to a particular port may be faulty).

Answer (score -1):

USB debugging can sometimes be hectic. I've faced similar issues without any reasons. The best thing you can do is, root your phone using any popular rooting software and then download [WIFI ADB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en). Its pretty simple and decent to use.

Comment: Gah. Not liking me at all today. "unable to connect to e:5555", "unable to connect to 1:5555". Even though my command is "adb connect 192.168.0.10". Also tried "adb connect 192.168.0.10:5555" explicitly. Nothing. Though, the app is telling me it is turned on and I have provided root access via SuperSU.

Comment: There's no need to install another app for that, you can use any terminal emulator app and type "setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555" and then "adbd stop" followed by "adbd start"